# Equivalence within Predicate Logic + Identity

Tags: logic

Do these 4 formulae stand equivalent when symbolizing the statement: 'There is exactly one dog'?

1) ∃x∀y(Dy ↔ y=x)

2) ∃x(Dx ∧ ∀y(Dy → x=y))

3) ∃x(Dx ∧ ¬∃y(¬y=x ∧ Dy))

4) ∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y)

Comment: Yes, they are all logically equivalent. Needless to say, the equivalence doesn't depend on that particular interpretation of 'D'; whatever 'D' means, (1-4) are equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) ∃x∀y(Dy ↔ y=x)
*There is something<sub>x</sub> such that: everything<sub>y</sub> is a dog just in case it<sub>y</sub> is identical to it<sub>x</sub>.*

2) ∃x(Dx ∧ ∀y(Dy → x=y))
*There is a dog and every dog is identical to it.*

3) ∃x(Dx ∧ ¬∃y(¬y=x ∧ Dy))
*There is a dog and there is nothing else that is a dog.*

4) ∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y)
*There is a dog, and any two things that are dogs are identical.*

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of how to prove the equivalence of these four formulae.

- (i) ⇒ (ii)

  1. ∃x∀y(Dy ⇔ y=x) — *premise*
  2. ∀y[ (Dy ⇒ y=d) & (y=d ⇒ Dy) ] — *by exemplar and pre-emptive biconditional elimination*
  3. (Dd ⇒ d=d) & (d=d ⇒ Dd) — *universal instantiation*
  4. d=d — *identity*
  5. Dd — *conjunctive elimination and modus ponens*
  6. (Da ⇒ a=d) & (Da ⇒ a=d) — *universal instantiation*
  7. Dd & (Da ⇒ a=d) — *conjunctive elimination/introduction*
  8. ∀y [Dd & (Dy ⇒ y=d)] — *universal generalization*
  9. ∃x∀y [Dx & (Dy ⇒ y=x)] — *existential introduction*
- (ii) ⇒ (iv)

  1. ∃x∀y [Dx & (Dy ⇒ y=x)] — *premise*
  2. ∀y [Dd & (Dy ⇒ y=d)] — *by exemplar*
  3. Dd & (Da ⇒ a=d) — *universal instantiation*
  4. Dd & (Db ⇒ b=d) — *universal instantiation again*
  5. Dd — *conjunctive elimination*
  6. ∃x (Dx) — *existential introduction*
  7. Da ⇒ a=d — *conjunctive elimination*
  8. Db ⇒ b=d — *conjunctive elimination again*
  9. (Da & Db) ⇒ (a=b) — *modus ponens/conditional introduction/conjunctive introduction/transitivity of equality/etc.*
  10. ∀x∀y[(Dx & Dy) ⇒ x=y] — *universal generalization*
  11. ∃x (Dx) & ∀x∀y[(Dx & Dy) ⇒ x=y] — *conjunctive introduction*
- (iv) ⇒ (i)

  1. ∃x (Dx) & ∀x∀y[(Dx & Dy) ⇒ x=y] — *premise*
  2. ∃x (Dx) — *conjunctive elimination*
  3. Dd  — *by exemplar*
  4. a=d ⇒ Da — *by modus ponens, substitution rule of equality, etc.*
  5. ∀x∀y [(Dx & Dy) ⇒ x=y] — *conjunctive elimination*
  6. (Dd & Da) ⇒ a=d  — *universal instantiation, twice*
  7. Da ⇒ a=d — *modus ponens (applying premise 3) and conditional introduction, etc.*
  8. Da ⇔ a=d — *biconditional introduction*
  9. ∀y (Dy ⇔ y=d) — *universal generalization*
  10. &exists;x ∀y (Dy ⇔ y=x) — *existential introduction*
- (ii) ⇔ (iii)
  — essentially by de Morgan's Law, involving some existential/universal quantifier juggling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very detailed and explanatory answer, but unfortunately it is beyond my current understanding of Logic (looks pretty straightforward, though). Reminds me of PC + Identity proofs a little; this is metalogical (Sequent Calculus?) stuff, right? I'll come back to this post when I'm more fluent.